# How to deserialize relaxed extended json or simplified json string in Python and get bson objects where appropriate?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, bson

I have a simplified json string such as follows:

```
j = '{"_id": {"_id": "5923e0e8bf681d1000abea4c", "copyingData": true}, "currency": "USD"}'
```

What I'd like to do is to deserialize it so that in return, I'd have a dictionary with `_id` as `bson.objectid` an `currency` as `string` - similar to the original document retrieved using pymongo.

How do I go about it?

I tried to use `bson.json_util.loads` with various arguments but it just loaded it as a simple json (so that _id is a `dict`)

Thank you!

Comment: I think you have a plain JSON string (rather than an _extended JSON_) as your input. See what is [Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/).

Comment: You are right - this is simplified json which is related to **relaxed** extended json